# jsTree removing node isn't actually removing it

Tags: jquery-plugins, jstree

hope you can help with a jsTree issue i'm having... only recently started to use it so still finding my feet.

I'm using a two jsTrees on the same page, (Available objects on the left and Included objects on the right) and i have several buttons in the middle that let users move objects from the left tree to the right tree and vice versa. I'm not using the dnd plugin and don't intend for users to be able to drag and drop between trees. My data structure is only two levels deep, parents and children/multiple children.

The other thing to mention is when i move a node from one tree to another, it is removed from that tree and created in the other tree.

So then problem i'm having is, i can select a node in the left tree (either a parent or one of its children) and i can move it to the right tree after clicking the button. If the node i selected is the parent, it moves the parent and all children. If the node i selected is the only child, it moves both the parent and the child. Lets stick with this scenario for this example. I do this by the following:

```
//Check to see if the parent exists in the right tree, if it doesn't create it
I've left this function call out for now but can post later if required
//Assuming the parent doesn't exist, create the parent in the right tree
$("#treeInc").jstree("create", null, false, { attr: { id: parent.id }, data: $(parent).children("a").text() }, false, true);
//Create the child in the right tree belonging to the parent node
$("#treeInc").jstree("create", $("#" + parent.id), "inside", { attr: { id: child.id }, data: $(child).children("a").text() }, false, true);

//Remove the parent and child from the left tree
$("#treeAvail").jstree("remove", $('#' + child.id));
$("#treeAvail").jstree("remove", $('#' + parent.id));
```

Now this all works great but the problem i have is when i try to move the nodes back to the left tree the parent always seems to exist in the data even thought is should have been removed. This means that i dont actually call the code to create the parent but only the child and it ends up hanging around on its own with no parent in sight.

So my logic is to first check to see if the parent exists by basically looking for the parent id in the nodes belonging to the right tree. I've done this several different ways so far and each time i fail.

I have called the 'get_json' function of the left tree to loop through the nodes but it exists in there. 
I loop round the array that i initially loaded the left tree from but that has all the nodes in from the initial load and never seems to change.
I've tried to use 'delete_node' instead of remove but that makes no difference.

So what am i doing wrong? If i remove a node from a jsTree, in terms of data, how could i check that tree to see that it has gone?

Please help, its driving me mad!!!

My actual tree data comes from a web service but for this example, the below json array will do.

```
availDataCache = [
        { attr: { id: "A_R1" }
          , data: "Report 1"
          , state: "open"
          , children: [{ attr: { id: "A_PSA1" }, data: "Param Set A"}]
        }
        , { attr: { id: "A_R2" }
            , data: "Report 2"
            , state: "open"
            , children : [ 
                  { attr: { id: "A_PSA2" }, data: "Param Set A" }
                  ,{ attr: { id: "A_PSB1" }, data: "Param Set B" }
                   ]
          }
        ];

$("#treeAvail").jstree({
    "json_data": {
        "data": availDataCache
    },
    "core": {
        "animation": 0
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "core", "crrm"]
});

$("#treeInc").jstree({
    "json_data": {
        "data": incDataCache
    },
    "core": {
        "animation": 0
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "core", "crrm"]
});
```

Comment: What version of `jstree` are you using? Some versions are very different from others.

Comment: Sorry, should have said... version 1.0-rc3, straight download from the site

Answer (score 0):

Try to call refresh function for both jstree after each copy,move,delete operation.

```
$("#leftjsTree").jstree("refresh" ,"#idOfLeftNode");
$("#rightjsTree").jstree("refresh" ,"#idOfRightNode");
```